# Apple LLVM 9.0 error no such file or directory: '[-Wunknown-warning-option]'

Tags: ios, xcode

When I create the 'Notification Service Extension' target in the Objective-C. Then build failure.
But Swift is Ok.

[image: error screen]

Comment: Please provide more context and the error in text form

Comment: @NicoHaase The text form is in the title